# Flutter align AppBar back button to right side

Tags: flutter, navigation

I am using `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl` on the `MaterialApp`:

```
return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
      ),
    );
```

Everything is aligned to right and works perfectly, except for the back button of the `AppBar`.

When you navigate to other pages (specifically I'm using `drawer`) the back button is aligned to the left and not to the right.

[image: appbar back button left aligned]

Navigation code:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => const SettingsView(),
  ),
);
```

"Settings" page:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Settings"))
    );
```

As you can see I didn't touch the `leading` property, I thought it should be automatically...

Comment: are you providing leading or default on navigation

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I added the code, below the image. thanks.

Comment: even though we have  wrap with `Directionality` we are getting  `TextDirection.ltr` on new route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `builder` to handle this.

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
      builder: (context, child) => Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: child ?? const SizedBox.shrink(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(Directionality.of(context).toString());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Settings"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand the issue, thanks! **EDIT**: I thought you are using just the `builder` property in flutter, but I see the `ProviderScope`. It's from riverpod?

Comment: Glad to help, yes riverpod. I am testing different question on same project, , that's why It still remains and didnt noticed